# Can someone help me about a Chart.js doughnut that doesn't appear?

Tags: html, chart.js

I've got an issue with a dougnut made with chart.js. It doesn't want to appear, without any error in my console.

Here is my HTML/JS part code :

```php
<div class="min-w-0 px-4 rounded-lg shadow-xs bg-gray-800">
    <h4 class="mb-2 font-semibold text-gray-300">Flags</h4>
    <canvas id="playersFlags" style="max-height: 80%; margin-top: 5%;"></canvas>
    <script>
        var flagsData = {
            labels: ['Neutre', 'Veteran', 'Veteran +', 'Fiable', 'Fiable +', 'Joueur parfait', 'Dernière chance', 'Fan de sanctions', 'Peu fiable', 'Très peu fiable', 'Première fois', 'Nouveau joueur'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [0,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,4,6,3,2],
                backgroundColor: ['#89898980', '#B4ED5180', '#98D52F80', '#33E93E80', '#2BB23380', '#00630680', '#E2000080', '#C1343480', '#AF515180', '#E2616180', '#F18C0C80', '#E7B54380'],
            }]
        };

        var playersFlagsElement = document.getElementById("playersFlags");
        var donutChar = new Chart(playersFlagsElement, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: flagsData,
            options: {
                elements: {
                    arc: {
                        borderColor: 'black',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                    }
                }
            }
        });                         
    </script>
</div>
```

And the part of the website :

[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpRV9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpRV9.png)

Does the issue could come of FiveM, because my page is generate in FiveM, through a Chrome subprocess Thanks by advance for your help ! :) (And have a good year :D )

Comment: If you are using chart.js latest version/4, it's probably an issue with your css classes; otherwise, without the definitions of those classes, the doughnut appears OK, see [codePen](https://codepen.io/kikon-do/pen/YzgyGMY).

Comment: Update: I identified the css classes as being part of a framework called "tailwind css"; using the CDN method indicated on the site for that to include tailwind css, the colors change, but the doughnut chart is still displayed [codepen](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/KKEdWVx). So, although your html isn't exactly the one  [recommended](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note) for responsive charts, the code you posted should produce a visible chart.

Comment: If you run some sort of browser automation, make sure that it waits enough time for the external scripts (tailwind, chart.js) to be loaded and the rendering process to complete.